# IIS Rule Convert To .htaccess Rule

Tags: .htaccess, iis, mod-rewrite, web-config

I need some help writing a .htaccess rule that:

1. Removed the .php extension from a file name
2. Rewrites variables.

So, a url like `www.example.com/contact-us/456/789` would be interpereted by the server as `www.example.com/contact-us.php?a=123&b=456&c=789`

The following IIS web.config rule works a treat (using a rewrite map):

```
<rule name="Dynamic Rewriting" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([^/]+)(?:/?([^/]+)?)(?:/?([^/]+)?)(?:/?([^/]+)?)/?$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{DynamicRewriting:{R:1}}" pattern="(.+)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/{C:1}.php?page={C:1}&amp;a={R:2}&amp;b={R:3}&amp;c={R:4}" />
</rule>

<rewriteMap name="DynamicRewriting">
    <add key="contact-us" value="contact-us" />
</rewriteMap>
```

Can anyone show me the .htaccess rule I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)(?:/?([^/]+)?)(?:/?([^/]+)?)(?:/?([^/]+)?)/?$ /$1.php?page=$1&a=$2&b=$3&c=$4 [L,QSA]
```